# javascript: array of all <select> items comes back undefined. why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, select, input, undefined

i have a series of `<input>` and `<select>` items intermingled.  i want to populate an array with these items as they appear on the page.

i created the `inputItemsArray` and the `selectItemsArray` the same way:

```
var inputItemsArray = document.getElementsById("formGroup").getElementsByTag("input");
var inputSelectArray = document.getElementsById("formGroup").getElementsByTag("select");
```

the `input` array works out just fine.  the `select` array returns undefined.  why?

what i'm trying to do is splice the contents of the `submit` array into the `input` array and THEN dump the values of those elements into a final array.

it works fine if i just use the `input` array, but because the `select` array is undefined...

here's the code:

```
var clientInputArray = document.getElementById("clientData").getElementsByTagName("input");
var clientSelectAray = document.getElementById("clientData").getElementsByTagName("select");

clientInputArray.splice(4,0,clientSelectArray[0]);  //  insert townType into array
clientInputArray.splice(5,0,clientSelectArray[1]);  //  insert province into array

console.log("clientInputArray: " + clientInputArray);

for (data in clientArray)
{
    if (clientArray[data].length != 0)
    {
        clientData.push(clientArray[data].value);
        console.log("data: " + data);
    } else {    //  because the last two elements of the array are empty...don't know why...
            break;
    }
}   
console.log("clientData: " + clientData);   
//clientData.push(companyName);
```

so, to restate: why does the `select` version return undefined?

WR!

Comment: Please post a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to reproduce this problem, and to help us to better help you. Successfully answering this question is dependant on seeing your JavaScript and your HTML...

Comment: here you go: [jsFiddle project](http://jsfiddle.net/WhiteRau/MMXKW/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var inputItemsArray = document.getElementsById("formGroup").getElementsByTag("input");
var inputSelectArray = document.getElementsById("**formsGroup**").getElementsByTag("select");
```

You have an 's' that should not be there in formsGroup... This is why you are getting undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is:

1. You are treating the result of [`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1938918D) as an Array, but it's actually a `NodeList`.
2. You are using lazy `for (a in b)` iteration of the results instead of a proper numeric for loop.

Here is an updated and simplified test: http://jsfiddle.net/MMXKW/2/

As you can see:

- The results of both of them have non-zero length.
- When you iterate using `for (a in b)` on a NodeList you also get the enumerable properties of `length` and `item`.

Instead, use:

```
var selects = myForm.getElementsByTagName('select');
for (var i=0,len=selects.length;i<len;++i){
  var select = selects[i];
  // ...
}
```

*As a side note, when you write `for (foo in bar)` you are also creating a global `foo` variable; you should normally use `for (var foo in bar)` when you actually need to enumerate properties of an object and not numeric values of an Array or Array-like object.*